# Why does puts() print an extra character in the end?

Tags: c, arrays, string, puts

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main()
{
char test [7];
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
scanf("%c",&test[i]);
puts(test);
getch();
return 0;
}
```

I am using DevC++ (University rules) and I know that gets() has no bounds check so I have intentionally used for() loop to enter a string. When I am entering a string greater than the size of the array, puts is printing an extra character. Why so ??

Sample Input: helloworld
Output: hellowos

Sample Input: Hellopeople
Output: Hellopep

Comment: There is no `gets`, please forget this function has ever existed. OTOH `fgets` is alive and well and you should be using it instead of your hand-written loop, which could in principle work had you not firgotten to terminate your string with the NUL character. Also what's with the intentional overflowing the 7 character long buffer with up to 10 characters?

Comment: UB multi-dupe.  Don't overrun array bounds, and note that SO is searchable.

Comment: @n.m. Intentional overflow was just to check behavior of puts in case of overflow.Can you explain me why puts() is printing more 8 characters when it should have printed only 7.And why the character printed is immediate next.

Comment: Checking how overflow works makes very little sense unless you know how things work without overflowing. (1) Remove the overflow and return to the normal non-overflowing behaviour. (2) Google what "null-terminated string" means. You need to be familiar with the concept before you ever touch a string in C.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you're overflowing memory. Your array only has enough for seven characters and you try to populate it with ten:

```
char test [7];             // Array indexes 0-6 allowed.
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)      // Array indexes 0-9 used.
    scanf("%c",&test[i]);
```

You can fix it (including allowing for a string terminator) with something like:

```
char test [11];            // Array indexes 0-10 allowed.
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)      // Array indexes 0-9 used.
    scanf("%c",&test[i]);
test[10] = '\0';           // And add string terminator before puts().
```

If you want a hardened user input function with buffer overflow protection, something built from `fgets()` is generally the best way in standard C. Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023895/how-to-read-string-entered-by-user-in-c/4023921#4023921), for example.

Answer (score 1):

You have a [buffer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow) as you try to store 10 characters into a buffer that can at-most store 7 elements

```
char test [7];
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
  scanf("%c",&test[i]);
```

You can fix this by making the buffer 10 elements(So that it can store 9 characters plus one for the `\0` at the end) and using this:

```
char test [10]; //10 elements long
scanf("%9s",test); //Get at-most 9 chars
```

or you can use [`fgets`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm) too.

Answer (score 0):

your `test` array is only 7 chars, while you read 10 chars into it via the `for` loop. This could crash.

Also `puts` will expect your string to be 0-terminated. You don't explicitly put a 0 after your chars, so the output will contain whatever garbage is after your chars, up until the first 0-byte.

Answer (score 0):

Your strings does not end with '\0'.